# In dataframe, validate phone nuber with country code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In dataframe, some contact numbers have prefixes (country code) and some haven't.

I want to fix and remove the unnecessary thing from numbers

**df1**

```
id  contact
1   +1(123)-456-7890
2   +552(123)-(456)-(7890)   
3   (+91)1234567890  // correct
4   123-456-7890     // by default add +1, if there is no code
5                    // Ignore NA cases
6   +11234567890    // separate country code from given number and formate it
```

**Ans**

```
id  contact
1   (+1)1234567890
2   (+552)1234567890
3   (+91)1234567890
4   (+1)1234567890
5   
6   (+1)1234567890
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy of the df and iterate over it, check if contact element starts with () with the [library re](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-regular-expression-tutorial) (findAll), apply a regex with a [regular expression](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-and-intuitive-guide-to-regular-expressions-404b057b1081) to format the contact element and ignores the blank elements.